# Write a program which contains iterative and recursive function to print the first 100 elements

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

Given this question

[image]

I am suppose to what the question said. That is print like the example below:

```
Eg.
n Iterative Recursive
1 1          1
2 3          3
3 6          6
4 10        10
.  .        . 
.  .        .
```

I was able to print n and recursive for my question using explicit formula.

```py
print("    n       Recursive")
def recursive(n):
    result = ((4 * n) - 1) - 14
    print("%5d" % n, end="")
    print("%12d" % result)
    if n == 100:
        return 0
    else:
        recursive(n + 1)
recursive(1)
```

I don't know what is iterative or how do print it out. Is it the same with recursive according to example above?

Comment: Your explicit formula doesn't solve the recurrence. Just check the first few terms. In any event, I suspect that the point of the recursive solution is to explicitly follow the recursive definition of `g`.

Comment: They mean recursion as in `g(n)` returns `g(n - 1) - 4`, until the base case. Not as a way to print the solved recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Iteration means going over each element one by one. I guess a simple for loop should do the job:

```
def iterative():
    for n in range(100):
        result = ((4 * n) - 1) - 14
        print("%5d" % n, end="")
        print("%12d" % result)
    return 0

iterative()
```

The "good" iterative function should rather look like this in order to print the correct values:

```
def iterative():
    # np being the previous value
    np = 14

    # starts from 2 since the first case is already assumed to known (14)
    # go up to the 100th number
    for n in range(2, 101):
        result = np - 4
        print("%5d" % n, end="")
        print("%12d" % result)
        np = result
    return 0

iterative()
```